# Selenium:Google Chrome Options and capabilities

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just wanted to know is it possible to set homepage of Chrome using capabilities and Chrome options in Selenium.

Comment: Did you want to open the webpage from selenium Webdriver using chrome browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to instantiate `ChromeDriver` with using both `DesiredCapabilities` and `ChromeOption`  to set your desired Homepage as below :-

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

 Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
preferences.put( "browser.startup.homepage", "http://my.home.page" );
preferences.put( "browser.startup.page", START_WITH_HOME_PAGE );

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

 capabilities.setCapability( ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. You're not setting the homepage in chrome using capability and chrome options like was asked. You are using capabilities and options, and then only navigating to the desired page using `driver.get()`

Comment: @ParkerBeck ah, thanks to point it out, actually I didn't  understand the question, now updated with correction.....:)

Comment: Hi Saurabh Gaur,please correct me, I am not able to get START_WITH_HOME_PAGE . Do we need to pass URL here?  I am geeting error that START_WITH_HOME_PAGE can't be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the capabilities you are trying to set here are options that you use to customize and configure **a ChromeDriver session.** 
Below are the keys which you can use to set for that **session**:

`"browser.startup.homepage", "startup.homepage_welcome_url", "startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional"` etc. 
You can pass URL for these or if you don't want you can also set something like : `"about:blank"` as value